# Sed. Save lines that are ending with specific file-type

Tags: sed, file-type

I have a textfile and would like to save all lines that are ending with .m2 or .M2. I tried several ways including this here

```
D:\filetype\core\sed.exe -n -e "s/^\(.*\)\.M2//" D:\filetype\listfile\test.txt > D:\filetype\listfile\test2.txt
```

But as result i only get a emtpy textfile, so i guess something is wrong with my code.

The other way was

```
D:\filetype\core\sed.exe -n -e "^/\(.*)\/.M2\/" D:\filetype\listfile\test.txt > D:\filetype\listfile\test2.txt
```

But in this case i wasn't able to locate the source of the error

> unknown command: `^'

Thanks if someone can see my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below `sed` command:

```
sed -n -e '/\.[mM]2$/p' <file_name>
```

This will print all the lines which have `.m2` or `.M2` at the end

Now comming to issues with your commands.  Your first command does:

```
sed -n -e "s/^\(.*\)\.M2//"
```

which is a `search and replace` command indiacated by `s` in the command. Syntax for this command is `s/search_text/replace_text/`. Now if you are look at your command carefully, you are searching for something and replacing it with `nothing` - as indicated by last `//` in your command - where `replace_text` is missing.

Your second command does

```
sed -n -e "^/\(.*)\/.M2\/"
```

which is incorrect syntax. General syntax of a sed command is :

```
sed -e 'line_range command'
```

where line range - which is **optional** - can be line numbers like`1`, `5` , `2-5`, or a regular expression like `/[gG]/`, `/[gG][iIuU]rl/`.
If `line_range` is missing, the first letter in sed command should be a command. In your case: `line_range` is missing - which is fine syntax wise -, however the first letter is `^` - which is **not** a sed command - because of which you are getting syntax error.

The command that I suggested is

```
sed -n -e '/\.[mM]2$/p'
```

Here, `line_range` is the regular expression `/\.[mM]2$/` - which says `"any line which has .m2 or .M2 at the end"`, and command is `p`, which is the letter for print command.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, i can now understand it better (and hopefully a lot of more people while searching google). I add it to my personal favorites here.

Answer (score 1):

Sed is mostly used to transform text. Why not use `grep` instead?

```
grep -i "\.m2$"
```

This will match case insensitively (`-i`) any line ending with `.m2`.

Comment: Good question, i think mainly because i wasn't able to figure out how this can be done with sed and the information can help me to understand it better. But off course, you are right, i will think about when to use sed and when grep.